# Project from view multiple times from different angles

Tags: uv

I'm having a problem finding out a way to project from top view and the side view so I texture better. It just replaces the current projection with the top view

[image: Top view with side projection]

So is it possible to project from view twice on the same image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you are looking for unless I misunderstand the question.

Once you've unwrapped everything once you can then use -> *UVMapping* -> *Project From View* on selected faces without changing what has already been mapped out.

[image]

Comment: Yup works perfect

Answer (score 3):

You can *Project from view* any number of times. Your selection is what gets projected.

Go to side view select just the faces you want projected from the side view. In edit mode press <kbd>U</kbd> then *project from view*.

Then go to the top view, select just the top (and bottom) faces, but leave the sides unselected and project from view.